# Indian Taxation policy on UK (foreign) income

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, india

I am looking for some advice. My wife and I have a joint NRO account in India. Here in the UK, I am a higher rate tax payer (40%). We sold a house in 2012 and although that required tax in India, it didn't require any in the UK as it was jointly owned and the capital gains was within the limit for annual exemption.

Subsequently I didn't get any further access to the account until the start of this year when I went back and got to know the amount of interest that had been credited. Because interest on the NRO account is taxed at 30.9%, I owe the remainder after tax credits to the HMRC which is 9.1% of the tax accrued over the last 3 years.

It is not a lot - about £140 in dues. My question is do I have to declare this, given my wife doesn't have to pay tax to HMRC as she doesn't work and her share of the account has also been taxed at 30.9%.

If I declare how does the process work? My worry is not so much about the tax as the penalties and the fines.

Comment: Did you sell a house in India and deposit the proceeds in your NRO account or did you sell a house in UK and deposit the proceeds into your NRO account? If you paid tax on the capital gains in India, and the gains are not taxable in UK anyway, why do you believe that you owe tax to HMRC?

Comment: I thought the question was asking about the tax on the interest on the account, but it's not explicit about that.

Comment: I have been unclear. It is the interest income from the proceeds of the sale.